# Let $\pi$ be a $ℍ_$-recursive projection of $ℍ_$ into . What does $ℍ_{(, Domain(\pi))}$ contain?

Tags: set-theory, computability-theory

Let the structure $\mathfrak{A} = (A, R_1, ..., R_n)$ be strongly acceptable iff $\mathfrak{A}$ is an acceptable structure (in the sense of Moschovakis' *Elementary Induction on Abstract Structures*), $\mathfrak{A}$ has a countable domain, there is isomorphic copy of the natural numbers $\mathcal{N}^{\mathfrak{A}}$ "living" in $\mathfrak{A}$, and there is an $\mathfrak{A}$-hyperelementary mapping of $A$ into $\mathcal{N}^{\mathfrak{A}}$.

Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be strongly acceptable, and let $\pi$ be a $ℍ_$-recursive projection of $ℍ_$ into  (we know it exists by the classic results of Barwise in *Admissible Sets and Structures* (II.5.14, V.5.3, and VI.4.11/12)). The domain of , $_{\pi}$, is $\Sigma$ over $\mathbb{H}YP_{\mathfrak{M}}$ and cannot be hyperelementary over : if it were, then $D_π$ would be in $ℍ_$, and thus, by $\Sigma$-replacement, it would be the case that $ℍ_$ ∈ $ℍ_$.

Consider now the structure $(,_{\pi})$.

1. **Is it the case that $ℍ_ \in ℍ_{(,_π)}$?** My fist intuition is as follows. $_π$ is in $ℍ_{(,_π)}$. But then, since $\forall x \in D_{\pi}\,.\,\exists y\,.\,x \in \pi(y)$, and $\Sigma$-replacement holds for $ℍ_{(,_π)}$, there is a $c = \{y \,:\,\exists x \in D_{\pi}\,.\,x \in \pi(y)\} \in ℍ_{(,_π)}$. But $c = ℍ_$ itself, and thus $ℍ_ \in ℍ_{(,_π)}$. Additionally, I have had this other thought:

- By theorem 3D.2 of Moschovakis' *Elementary Induction on Abstract Structures*, for any $Q$ that is inductive non-hyperlementary on $\mathfrak{M}$, for any $P \subseteq M^n$, it is the case that $Q$ is hyperelementary on $(\mathfrak{M}, P)$ iff $\kappa^{\mathfrak{m}} < \kappa^{(\mathfrak{M}, P)}$.
  Clearly, since $D_{\pi}$ is $\Sigma$ on $\mathbb{H}YP_{\mathfrak{M}}$, $D_{\pi}$ is inductive on $\mathfrak{M}$, and cannot be hyperelementary on $\mathfrak{M}$ (otherwise it would be in $\mathbb{H}YP_{\mathfrak{M}}$, and we have seen that this is impossible). Thus, we can apply Moschovakis 3D.2 instantiating both $Q$ and $P$ with $D_{\pi}$. We get that $D_{\pi}$ is hyperelementary on $(\mathfrak{M}, D_{\pi})$ iff $\kappa^{\mathfrak{m}} < \kappa^{(\mathfrak{M}, D_{\pi})}$. Since $D_{\pi}$ is hyperelementary on $(\mathfrak{M}, D_{\pi})$, $\kappa^{\mathfrak{m}} < \kappa^{(\mathfrak{M}, D_{\pi})}$. So, the ordinal of  $ℍ_{(,_π)}$ must be stricly above the ordinal of $\mathbb{H}YP_{\mathfrak{M}}$.
- This also implies that the inductive relations on $\mathfrak{M}$ are hyperelementary on $ℍ_{(,_π)}$. By result 6D.2 of Moschovakis, we conclude that for any $n \in \omega$, the collection $\mathbb{H}YP^n_{\mathfrak{M}} = \{X \subseteq M^n\,:\,X \text{ is hyperelementary on }\mathfrak{M}\}$ is a set in $\mathbb{H}YP_{(\mathfrak{M}, D_{\pi})}$ since it is inductive on $\mathfrak{M}$. Since $\mathfrak{M}$ is strongly acceptable, then it holds true in  $\mathbb{H}YP_{(\mathfrak{M}, D_{\pi})}$ that $\forall n \in \mathcal{N}^{\mathfrak{M}}\,.\,\exists a\,.\,a = \mathbb{H}YP^n_{\mathfrak{M}}$.
  Consequently, the collection $b = \{a : \exists n \in \mathcal{N}^{\mathfrak{M}}\,.\,a = \mathbb{H}YP^n_{\mathfrak{M}}\}$ is a set in $\mathbb{H}YP_{(\mathfrak{M}, D_{\pi})}$. The union $\bigcup b$ belongs to $\mathbb{H}YP_{(\mathfrak{M}, D_{\pi})}$, too, and $\bigcup b = \mathbb{H}YP_{\mathfrak{M}}$ according to the definition in 6D of Moschovakis. Hence, when $\mathfrak{M}$ is strongly acceptable, $\mathbb{H}YP_{\mathfrak{M}} \in \mathbb{H}YP_{(\mathfrak{M}, D_{\pi})}$.

2. Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the standard model of arithmetic, and $\pi^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a projection of $\mathbb{H}YP_{\mathbb{N}}$ into $\omega$, having domain $D_{\pi}^{\mathbb{N}}$. **What is the ordinal of $ℍ_{(\mathbb{N},D_{\pi}^{\mathbb{N}})}$?**.  If the reasoning above is correct, it should be strictly above the ordinal of $ℍ_{\mathbb{N}}$.

Thank you for your help!

(Also asked on Math Stackexchange, link here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4742349/1080052)

Comment: Please indicate that this is a cross-post by putting links in both posts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following result will immediately give the answer to your second question:

> **Proposition.** Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be strongly acceptable and $\pi\colon \mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}\to\mathfrak{M}$ be a $\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}$-recursive projection of domain $D_\pi$. Then $\mathrm{HYP}_{\mathfrak{M},D_\pi}$ is the next admissible set of $\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}$. That is, $\mathrm{HYP}_{\mathfrak{M},D_\pi}=\mathrm{HYP}_{\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}}$.
>
> *Proof.* It suffices to claim that if $A$ is an admissible set, then  $\mathfrak{M}, D_\pi\in A$ if and only if $\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}\in A$. If $\mathfrak{M}, D_\pi\in A$, then by the argument you gave, we can reconstruct $\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}$ inside $A$: More precisely, let $\phi(x,y)$ be a $\Sigma_1$ formula equivalent to $x\in \pi(y)$ over $\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}$. Since $\mathfrak{M}\in A$, $\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}\subseteq A$. Since
> $$\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}\models \forall x\in D_\pi \exists y \phi(x,y),$$
> we can see that $\forall x\in D_\pi \exists y \phi(x,y)$ also holds over $A$.
> Then by $\Sigma$-Collection over $A$ (Theorem I 4.4. of Barwise), we get a set $c\in A$ such that
> $$\forall x\in D_\pi \exists y\in c\phi(x,y)\land \forall x\in c\exists y\in D_\pi \phi(x,y).$$
> However, we know that every $x\in D_\pi$ belongs to $\pi(y)$ for a precisely one $y\in \mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}$, in other words, $\forall x\in D_\pi \exists! y\in\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M} \phi(x,y)$ so $c=\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}$.
>
> The converse is easy. If $\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}\in A$, then clearly $\mathfrak{M}\in A$. Also, since $D_\pi$ is $\Sigma$ definable over $\mathrm{HYP}_\mathfrak{M}$, $D_\pi\in A$ by bounded Separation applied to $A$.

You can see that $\mathrm{HYP}_\mathbb{N}$ is $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, where $\omega_1^{CK}$ is the least admissible ordinal. Thus $\mathrm{HYP}_{(\mathbb{N},D_\pi)}$ is $L_{\omega_2^{CK}}$, where $\omega_2^{CK}$ is the second least admissible ordinal.

Comment: (A tiny complaint about your question: I think your question is better suited for `computability` than `model-theory`.)

Comment: Dear @Hanul Jeon, thank you so much! Also, I'll go ahead and change the tag now. I tried looking for tags like "admissibility theory" or "generalized recursion", but couldn't find them and I cannot create new tags. Thanks for the tip, too!

Comment: @SimPic Thank you for hearing my comment, but computational complexity is unrelated to your question, which is about computational complexity below recursively enumerable sets.

Comment: thanks again! Fixed :)